# Fitting values to a Binomial Distribution with Julia

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia and want to understand how to fit some values to a binomial distribution and get their parameters:

```
d = Distributions.fit_mle(Binomial, [1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.4, 2.0, 1.4, 1.3, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 2.0, 2.2, 2.6, 2.9, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 2.0, 1.6, 1.0])
```

When I run this a get the following error:

```
suffstats is not implemented for (Binomial, Array{Float64,1}).
```

Well I know that one you run other distributions like the `Normal` you do get the parameters. So there are two questions first is how do I fit the above data to a `Binomial` distribution? The second is why I can't use `Binomial` with `fit` or `fit_mle` from `Distrbutions`?

Answer (score 2):

For a starter, the binomial distribution is usually defined over the integers, and you gave it an array of floats (and `Distributions` does expect integers as well).  What does that data of yours even mean?  If you are interested in a binomial distribution over a finite set of non-integer values, I think the best alternative would be to map your data to unique integers and fit the distribution on them.

Secondly, there is no MLE in terms of sufficient statistics for the size parameter of the binomial distribution (it is an [exponential family only over *p*, not *N*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Binomial_distribution)).  You must pass it to `fit_mle`.  I didn't think of this myself, but found it out by looking at the respective methods of `suffstats`; for example:

```
julia> methods(suffstats)
...
[7] suffstats(::Type{#s29} where #s29<:Binomial, n::Integer, x::AbstractArray{T,N} where N) where T<:Integer in Distributions at /home/philipp/.julia/packages/Distributions/dTXqn/src/univariate/discrete/binomial.jl:195
...
```

Combining both requirements:

```
julia> data = rand(Binomial(5, 0.2), 10)
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 0
 1
 1
 0
 0
 2
 1
 1
 1

julia> fit_mle(Binomial, 5, data)
Binomial{Float64}(n=5, p=0.18)
```

Comment: ah okay, I did not know it would work only with integers, I will try it out now

Comment: You should always understand your distributions before using them! The prototype of a binomial distribution is the sum of heads after throwing  the same coin _N_ times.

Comment: (See, I was even mixing it up with a multinomial distribution. Happens.)